# How to submit custom input field data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am creating custom input field in html.Now i am facing problem how to submit data by using these custom fields. Custom field may be a radio option, may be it a select option, text field etc etc using can write name of that field by his own choice i want to know how to submit data of that fields in php and jquery.

```
<div id="custom fields">
  //custom fields data
</div>
```

Is there any way to submit whole div fields with value ..If i write name in input text field and submit then my complete input filed and its value will save in database? when i retrieve these fields it will show input with value?

Comment: in Javascript use formData()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch multiple values than take a form else go for jQuery selector.

**For multiple values (includes every types of DOM elements)**
HTML :- `<form id="formID"> ...... </form>`
Access the form elements by using jQuery `serialize` function
**NOTE** :- `serializeArray` creates an array (**not** a "json array" -- there is no such thing); you can test this yourself with `console.log($("#formID").serializeArray())`. On the other hand, `serialize` creates a query string that's meant to be part of an HTTP request. Both representations are equivalent in the sense that using appropriate code you can convert one to the other without any ambiguity.
Example :- `$("#formID").serialize();` OR `$("#formID").serializeArray();`

**For single value**
HTML :- `<input id="name">`
Javascript :- `document.getElementById("name");`
jQuery :- `$("#name").val();`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="customfields">
  //custom fields data
</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById("customfields").value = document.getElementById("customfields").innerHTML;
}, 5);
</script>
```

Comment: thank its show input text field but not showing the value of that input fields. I want to like this `<input type="text" value="abc">` but its not showing any value whatever user can enter

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit fields in between div tag. Please use form tag to submit fields.

```
<form></form>
```

Comment: how i know in php field name because user create and change field name . I am trying to submit div html with data that why i write in div .Div fields was submitted but without its value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you find this?
[$( "form" ).serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Is this function submit html fields with data? and when i retrieve it will show that fields with data?

Comment: This function is not submit html fields data. If you use this function, you can convert input and option and etc.. to http parameter string. check this link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzo6w3r6/)

Comment: If you want submit html fields with data, you can use this function with [$Jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). [sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/jzo6w3r6/1/)